# What differential calculation rule is applied here?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

On my way to electronics I stumbled upon this mathematical equation rearrangement. I cannot understand the mathematics behind this, so maybe the community could help me.
This is, what the rearrangement of the equation looks like:

$$K_I = \beta = \frac{dI_C}{dI_B} = \frac{dI_C}{d(I_E - I_C)} (1)= \frac{dI_C / dI_E}{1 - dI_C / dI_E} (2)$$

What You probably need to know is, that $I_B = I_E - I_C$.
So, the questions, how does the 1 Eq get rearranged to the 2nd? What rules are applied? Could someone give a brief explanation?

Comment: $d(I_E - I_C)=dI_E - dI_C$

Comment: Then (for denominator) $\dfrac {dI_E - dI_C}{dI_E} = 1- \dfrac {dI_C}{dI_E}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply expand $\mathrm d(I_E-I_C)=\mathrm dI_E-\mathrm dI_C$, then divide the numerator and denominator by $\mathrm dI_E$. $$\frac{\mathrm dI_C}{\mathrm d( I_E-I_C)}=\frac{\mathrm dI_C}{\mathrm dI_E-\mathrm dI_C}=\frac{\frac{\mathrm dI_C}{\mathrm dI_E}}{\frac{\mathrm d I_E}{\mathrm dI_E}-\frac{\mathrm dI_C}{\mathrm dI_E}}=\frac{\frac{\mathrm dI_C}{\mathrm dI_E}}{1-\frac{\mathrm dI_C}{\mathrm dI_E}}$$

Comment: So it works so simple $d(I_E - I_C)$ = $dI_E -d I_C$ ?

Comment: Yes, since the differential operator is linear, so you can expand it in this way

Answer (score 1):

In the first differential, $I_C$ is a function of $I_B$, which with the relation of $I_B$ leads to an implicit equation for $I_C$
$$
I_C=f(I_B)=f(I_E-I_C).
$$
This implicit equation has, under favorable conditions, a solution $I_C=g(I_E)$. The two functions are connected as
$$
g(I_E)=I_C=f(I_E-g(I_E))
$$
where now the chain rule can be applied to
$$
g'(I_E)=f'(I_E-g(I_E))(1-g'(I_E))\implies f'(I_B)=\frac{g'(I_E)}{1-g'(I_E)}
$$
or in the differential quotients
$$
\frac{dI_C}{dI_B}=f'(I_B)=\frac{\frac{dI_C}{dI_E}}{1-\frac{dI_C}{dI_E}}.
$$